# How can I use fetchmail (or another email grabber) with OSX keychain for authentication?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, security, passwords, fetchmail, msmtp

Many fetchmail tutorials I've read say putting your email account password clear-text in a config file is safe. However, I prefer security through layers **[***silly example:* if my terminal is up and someone suspecting such email foolery slides over and simply types "grep -i pass ~/.*" then, oops, all my base are belong to them! especially if my email provider uses openid (or I'm dumb enough to use the same password for my bank)**]**.

Now, with msmtp (as opposed to sendmail) I can authenticate using the OSX keychain. Is there a free/open-source email 'grabber' that lets me use Keychains (specifically the OSX keychain) or at least, that lets me MD5 the password?

This is a duplicate of [my question on serverfault.](https://serverfault.com/questions/149452/how-can-i-use-fetchmail-or-another-email-grabber-with-osx-keychain-for-authenti) I've put it on superuser because I'm doing this on a personal computer (viz. with OSX) so it's a superuser question too.

Comment: Doesn't OS X have a "Lock workstation" feature?

Comment: Sure, but, there is a ~3 second window where if you move the mouse or hit a key it doesn't lock. That's why I said security through layers. Just because your house has a locked door doesn't mean you shouldn't keep your passport etc. in a safe. Hence, why would one leave a password as cleartext with only thier user (and admin group) permission? It's asking for something bad to happen.

Comment: Now, with open ID this is especially dangerous since people are likely to have an email account that can access many other web sites (viz. gmail and openid). So, if this gets taken, it's more than just email that is compromised.

Comment: cross-posted as http://serverfault.com/questions/149452/how-can-i-use-fetchmail-or-another-email-grabber-with-osx-keychain-for-authent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write a script to use [getmail_fetch](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/configuration.html#running-fetch) and submit your password using `security(1)`.

For example:

```
getmail_fetch --ssl $server \
  $user \
  $(security find-internet-password -g -s $server -a $user 2>&1 1>&- | sed -e 's/password: "\(.*\)"/\1/') \
  $destination
```

You will need to click "Always Allow" the first time you access a particular keychain item with `security`.